# Java Multithreading With For Loops Issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an odd issue.

I create and run a new `thread` like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TIMES_TO_CALL_PING; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                            "ping -l " + PACKET_SIZE + " -n "
                                    + TIMES_TO_PING_PER_CALL + " "
                                    + ADDRESS);

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String input;
                    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (input.contains("time=")) {
                            totalPingTime += Integer.parseInt(input
                                    .split("time=")[1].split("ms")[0]);
                            average = (double) (totalPingTime / index);
                            pingTime.setText("Average Ping Time: "
                                    + average + "ms");

                            System.out.println(index);
                        }
                        output.append(input + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        index = i;
        pingCount.setText("Pings called: " + (i + 1));
        frame.pack();
    }
```

And the output of the program is:
http://pastebin.com/E2fjczSq

Notice how the program prints "9999" forever (it never stops) and how the numbers aren't in order like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Why is this happening?

Comment: why do you think, they should be ordered? you running multiple threads, that concurently printing to console...

Comment: Instead of expecting us to infer your intent from the code, you need to state it first. I'm pretty sure that your intent and what the code is doing are two different things.

Comment: Why are you using multithreading to being with?  You seem to be creating a whole lot of threads that all run at the same time and all run "ping" processes that will all be making ping requests to the same address.  Is there a purpose for doing it this way?  I don't think we can really help solve your problem without knowing what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to `capture` `index` variable value for each thread on thread start, rewrite thread instantiation to following:

```
class OVThread extends Thread {

    int index;

    public OVThread(int index, Runnable target) {
        super(target);
        this.index = index;
    }

}
```

Now you can use it as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TIMES_TO_CALL_PING; i++) {
    new OVThread(index, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    ...
}
```